# How to add passwd command to system builder project?

Tags: linux, configuration, qnx, qnx-neutrino, momentics

I have a system builder project to make a QNX OS image that needs to be accomplished. The problem is it is not currently supporting passwd command. I mean when I write the image and try **passwd root** command, I get this output:

```
/bin/passwd[1]: root::0:0:Superuser:/root:/bin/sh: cannot execute - No such file or directory
/bin/passwd[2]: bin:x:1:1:Binaries: cannot execute - No such file or directory
/bin/passwd[3]: daemon:x:2:2:System: cannot execute - No such file or directory
/bin/passwd[4]: mail:x:8:40:User: cannot execute - No such file or directory
/bin/passwd[5]: news:x:9:50:Network: cannot execute - No such file or directory
/bin/passwd[6]: uucp:x:12:60:Network: cannot execute - No such file or directory
/bin/passwd[7]: ftp:x:14:80:FTP: cannot execute - No such file or directory
/bin/passwd[9]: nobody:x:99:99:Nobody:/:: cannot execute - No such file or directory
```

I have already added passwd binary to **Binaries** part of the project but the problem is not solved. I am new to image building concepts. What steps should I take?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was all an unwanted override! In my overrides folder I had a **passwd** (the one that usually sits in etc folder) which was replacing the binary in **/bin** folder and causing the problem.