# Why creating a file in etc folder is not allowed?

Tags: configuration, qnx, momentics

I have a system builder project to make a QNX OS image that needs to be accomplished. The problem is I can't create files or folders in **etc** folder. When I try to do that I get "*folder creation error! reason: function not implemented*" or "*no such file or directory*". 
I haven't build this myself. Where should I look for to solve it? etc permission is  777.

Answer (score 1):

Default QNX image has [Image Filesystem](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/660/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.qnx.doc.neutrino.user_guide%2Ftopic%2Ffsystems_NFS.html&resultof=%22mount%22%20%22remote%22%20%22filesystem%22) (the link is weird, just find "image silesystem" there) and it doesn't support folders and files creation.

For your perposes you can use:

- RAM fs (/dev/shmem, clears on reboot)
- Flash devices (USB key, eMMC)
- Network fs
- devb like SATA

To work with exactly **/etc** dir you can create virtual flash from RAM and mount it as **/etc**. Use **devf-ram** in this case

Comment: Can you check this too please? They're related together. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40086000/how-to-add-passwd-command-to-system-builder-project

Comment: When I run these commands it has no effect:
# cd /etc
# df
/dev/fs0p1                100096        79    100016       1%  /fs0p1          
# devb-ram ram capacity=2000 &
[1] 155663
# Path=0 - 
 target=0 lun=0     Direct-Access(0) - ram  Rev: 


[1] + Done                 devb-ram ram capacity=20
# df
/dev/fs0p1                100096        79    100016       1%  /fs0p1          
#